# How to synchronize data-attr and select box vaule?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements like:

```
<select id="data">
  <option value=1>hoge</option>
  <option value=2>fuga</option>
  <option value=3>hogehoge</option>
</select>

<a href="#1" data-id="1">hoge</a>
<a href="#2" data-id="2">fuga</a>
<a href="#3" data-id="3">hogehoge</a>
```

if I pick hoge on select box, I want data-id="1" to be selected and do some stuff (changing background etc.) using jQuery.
If I click `a[data-id="3"]`, select box option 'hogehoge' to be selected vice versa.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: man use `$(a).attr("data-id")`

Comment: Read the data attribute and set the value of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the last line in the click listener. You can trigger a change on an element which will call the corresponding listener instead of duplicating code.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $("#data").on("change", function() {
    $("a").removeClass("active"); // remove active class from all <a>
    $("a[data-id='" + $(this).val() + "']").addClass("active"); // add active class to link with corresponding data-id
  });
  
  $("a").on("click", function() {
    $("#data option[value='" + $(this).data("id") + "']").prop("selected", true); // change the selected value
    $("#data").trigger("change"); // trigger change on #data to keep active link synced
  });
  
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="data">
  <option value=1>hoge</option>
  <option value=2>fuga</option>
  <option value=3>hogehoge</option>
</select>

<a href="#1" data-id="1" class="active">hoge</a>
<a href="#2" data-id="2">fuga</a>
<a href="#3" data-id="3">hogehoge</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#data').find('option[value='+id+']').prop('selected',true);
    )};
)};
```

I implemented the function in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dphf267u/